# How does this backtracking code ensure that the two strings don't have common elements?

Tags: c++, algorithm, backtracking, disjoint-sets

I am trying [this question on LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-product-of-the-length-of-two-palindromic-subsequences/):

> Given a string s, find two disjoint palindromic subsequences of `s` such that the product of their lengths is maximized. The two subsequences are disjoint if they do not both pick a character at the same index.  Return the maximum possible product of the lengths of the two palindromic subsequences.  For e.g., if `s = "leetcodecom"`, the output should be `9` (two strings are `ete` and `cdc`, etc.).

With some online help, I came up with the code below:

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    int res;
    
    bool isPalindrome(string& s) {
        int i=0, j=s.size()-1;
        while(i<j && s[i]==s[j]) {
            i++;
            j--;
        }
        return i>=j;
    }
    
    void helper(string& s, string& s1, string& s2, int start) {
        if(start>=s.size()) {
            if(isPalindrome(s1) and isPalindrome(s2)) {
                res=max((int)res, (int)s1.size()*(int)s2.size());
            }
            return;
        }

        s1+=s[start];
        helper(s, s1, s2, start+1);
        s1.pop_back();
        
        s2+=s[start];
        helper(s, s1, s2, start+1);
        s2.pop_back();
        
        helper(s, s1, s2, start+1);
    }
    
    int maxProduct(string s) {
        res=0;
        string s1, s2;
        helper(s, s1, s2, 0);
        
        return res;
    }
};
```

This works and gets ACed, but I am unsure how it ensures that the two strings are *disjoint*.  I was expecting to have a check that would ensure this and update `res` iff the two strings are disjoint.

What gives?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code ensures disjointness because the two recursive steop blocks in `helper` do not ever pull the same character into both `s1` and `s2`.

Firstly, each call to `helper` will not return until processing the string until the end, including all the recursive cases which that triggers. Then the `pop_back` will return the respective sequence to its original value, at this level of recursion.

```
    s1+=s[start];
    helper(s, s1, s2, start+1);
    s1.pop_back();
    
    s2+=s[start];
    helper(s, s1, s2, start+1);
    s2.pop_back();
```

Whenever the first block finishes and control falls through to the second block, `s1` is rewound back to the value it had on entry into this recursion level. Some of the same characters that were previously put into `s1` get added to `s2`. But they never appear in both at the same time.

```
    helper(s, s1, s2, start+1);
```

This line advances the recursion to search for subsequences starting at all positions. But here, no characters are added to `s1` or `s2`. Just the `start` index moves ahead. So again, since no characters are added, no common character can be added.

Throughout the recursion, `s1` and `s2` contain potentially interleaving subsequences of `s`, but no character from `s` ever appears in `s1` and `s2` at the same time.

This is hard to follow because it isn't functional recursion, due to the sequences being passed by reference and being destructively manipulated. It's a kind of iterative process that uses recursion to furnish it with a back-tracking stack; a push-down automaton, loosely speaking. It doesn't even return a value; its output is a side-effect on a member variable scoped outside of the recursion.

You have to intuit that the `s2+=s[start];` and `s2.pop_back()` are balanced, paired stack-like operations, which bring the sequence to the same state, regardless of what went on in the recursion below (because the recursion below executed the same balanced push/pop pairs). Furthermore, the recursion below is always at `start + 1`, and moves only toward the right, so **it** will never add the same character to either subsequence. So we can see there is a local mutual exclusion in the same frame, plus mutual exclusion against the lower recursion frames.

Comment: Very intuitive explanation.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At first glance it looks like DP (dynamic programming).

The initial problem sounds like this.

> Given a string s, find two disjoint palindromic subsequences of s such that the product of their lengths is maximized.

`helper` solves a more generic version of this problem:

> Given a string s, find two disjoint palindromic subsequences of s **with the specified prefixes s1 and s2** such that the product of their lengths is maximized.

It does so using recursion. We may break all imaginable cases into three categories:

1. The first letter is the part of the first subsequence, in which case we append this letter to the prefix `s1` and solve the same problem for the rest of the string `s`.
2. The first letter is the part of the second subsequence, in which case we append this letter to the prefix `s2` and solve the same problem for the rest of the string `s`.
3. The first letter is neither part of the first nor the second subsequence in which case we may ignore this letter and just solve the problem for the rest of the string `s`.

The three recursive calls to `helper` exactly correspond to these three cases. From these the construction of these cases you may see that none of the letters may apper in both sequences at the same time.

Getting closer to the question. During recursive calls to `helper` each character of the initial string `s` can only appear in `s1` (1st case) or `s2` (2nd case) or be rejected (3rd case). You may see this precisely in the code. The character gets put into `s1` then recursive call happens, then it gets poped, then it gets put into `s2`, then recusive call happens, it gets poped, then again recursive call.

Comment: I follow that, but not how it ensures that a particular character won't be a part of both s1 and s2 _simultaneously_. Could you please elaborate on _that_?

Comment: @Someone I extended the answer with little more explanation.

Comment: ok, I see what you mean.  Since we pop it from `s1`, before appending it to `s2`, we can confirm that the two strings `s1` and `s2` won't have the same character(s).  Thank you!